# Rails find confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please help me get the include right.

```
Poem 
  has_many :awards
  has_one  :overall_ranking

Award
  belongs_to :poem
  # before
  # has_one :overall_ranking, :foreign_key => :poem_id 
  ## SOLUTION
  # after
  has_one :overall_ranking, :foreign_key => :poem_id, :primary_key => :poem_id

OverallRanking
  belongs_to :poem

update: Award.all(:include => [:overall_ranking]) # works with SOLUTION
```

Please note that I cannot depend on `Poem#id` as users may delete the poem, but if it's a winner, I make a copy within `Award`, so I must depend only on `Award#poem_id` Thank you!

Comment: Updated my post, please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that:

```
has_one :overall_ranking, :foreign_key => :poem_id
```

means that Award has one OverallRanking and that the ID of Award in has_one relation is in column poem_id, i.e. your logic is wrong.

It would make more sense if you would just use:

```
@award.poem.overall_rating
```

Or in find:

```
Award.all(:include => [:poem => {:overall_ranking}])
```

Comment: Hm. You can then specify :primary_key option which will tell Rails what attribute from Award you want to use for relation. For example: has_one :overall_ranking, :foreign_key => :poem_id, :primary_key => :poem_id

Comment: Now the original find works: Award.all(:include => :overall_ranking)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give some more information but I hope this helps:

You might want to try `joins`.

For example:

```
Award.all(:joins => :overall_ranking, :conditions => ['some_attribute_from_overall_ranking=?', true])
```

So this will find awards and `include` the overall_ranking.

Comment: In Award.all I need the poem_id for the record it joins.  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Award.all(:joins => :overall_ranking, :conditions => ["poem_id = ?", self.poem_id]) ???

Comment: Award.all(:joins => "LEFT JOIN `overall_rankings` ON awards.poem_id = overall_rankings.poem_id") ???

Comment: Award.all(:joins => "LEFT JOIN overall_rankings as overall_ranking ON awards.poem_id = overall_rankings.poem_id") ???

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion for me.

```
Award
  belongs_to :poem
  has_one :overall_ranking, :foreign_key => :poem_id
```

Here you are using the same id for both relation. This means that you try to retrieve the overall ranking with the poem id.
If I translate to sql you say something like:

```
overall_ranking.id = poem_id
```

I think this is wrong.

If you like to have the same `overall_ranking` for `award` and `poem` you can write something like this:

```
Award.rb
  belongs_to :poem
  has_one :overall_ranking, :through=>:poem
```

You can include like

```
Award.all(:include => [:overall_ranking])
or nested
Award.all(:include => [{:poem=>:overall_ranking}])
```

**Update**

1.Your has one association is set up incorrectly.

Please see: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality

```
Award
  belongs_to :poem
  belongs_to :overall_ranking, :foreign_key => :poem_id

OverallRanking
  belongs_to :poem
  has_one :award
```

You always should have belongs_to at the model where you store the referencing id.
  2. But this not resolves your problem in your logic.
     With this you will still has association between `Award#poem_id = OverallRanking#id`. You should have `Award#poem_id = OverallRanking#poem_id`.

I suggest to add `overall_ranking_id` to `Award` and things become much cleaner.

Comment: see edit above.  I can't depend on Poem#id because Award is a separate copy just using the poem_id.  Award makes a copy in case user deletes the poem (so I can keep the award visible). thankyou